# I trained Yolo v3 using my own data, but prediction shows class I did not train

Tags: object-detection, training-data, yolo

I'm trying to make a Yolo v3 model for detecting traffic lights for each color.

So I started to train Yolo v3 using my own data of traffic lights.

The classes I set are six.

red light, green light, yellow light, left turn, go straight and left turn, right turn.
(I will make these 4 classes.)

After training, I run Yolo v3 detector by my own Weight and cfg file.

But prediction showed an unexpected result!

Its class had nothing to do with what I've set. Like car, aeroplane, motobike...

What's wrong with this?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and GForce RTX 2080. OpenCV, CUDA, CuDNN also.
So makefile of darknet has been set like this.

```
    GPU=1
    CUDNN=1
    OPENCV=1
    OPENMP=0
    DEBUG=0
    ...
```

I used pre-trianed weight darknet19_448.conv.23.
I heard it is needed.

Add my cfg file for training I've set.

```
    [net]
    # Testing
    #batch=1
    #subdivisions=1
    # Training
    batch=24
    subdivisions=8
    width=416
    height=416
    channels=3
    momentum=0.9
    decay=0.0005
    angle=0
    saturation = 1.5
    exposure = 1.5
    hue=.1

    learning_rate=0.001
    burn_in=1000
    max_batches = 20000
    policy=steps
    steps=400000,450000
    scales=.1,.1

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=32
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    # Downsample

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=64
    size=3
    stride=2
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=32
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=64
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    # Downsample

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=128
    size=3
    stride=2
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=64
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=128
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=64
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=128
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    # Downsample

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=3
    stride=2
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=128
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=128
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=128
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=128
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear


    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=128
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=128
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=128
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=128
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    # Downsample

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=3
    stride=2
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear


    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear


    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear


    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear


    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear


    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    # Downsample

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=1024
    size=3
    stride=2
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=1024
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=1024
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=1024
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=1024
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [shortcut]
    from=-3
    activation=linear

    ######################

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    filters=1024
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    filters=1024
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=512
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    filters=1024
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    filters=33
    activation=linear


    [yolo]
    mask = 6,7,8
    anchors = 10,13,  16,30,  33,23,  30,61,  62,45,  59,119,  116,90,  156,198,  373,326
    classes=6
    num=9
    jitter=.3
    ignore_thresh = .7
    truth_thresh = 1
    random=1


    [route]
    layers = -4

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [upsample]
    stride=2

    [route]
    layers = -1, 61



    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    filters=512
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    filters=512
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=256
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    filters=512
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    filters=33
    activation=linear


    [yolo]
    mask = 3,4,5
    anchors = 10,13,  16,30,  33,23,  30,61,  62,45,  59,119,  116,90,  156,198,  373,326
    classes=6
    num=9
    jitter=.3
    ignore_thresh = .7
    truth_thresh = 1
    random=1



    [route]
    layers = -4

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=128
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [upsample]
    stride=2

    [route]
    layers = -1, 36



    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=128
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    filters=256
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=128
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    filters=256
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    filters=128
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    batch_normalize=1
    size=3
    stride=1
    pad=1
    filters=256
    activation=leaky

    [convolutional]
    size=1
    stride=1
    pad=1
    filters=33
    activation=linear


    [yolo]
    mask = 0,1,2
    anchors = 10,13,  16,30,  33,23,  30,61,  62,45,  59,119,  116,90,  156,198,  373,326
    classes=6
    num=9
    jitter=.3
    ignore_thresh = .7
    truth_thresh = 1
    random=1
```

I would really appreciate it if you answer me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What repository are you using?

There should also be some `.data` or `.names` files somewhere that you should change. Take a look at [this page](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects) for example. You need to change **number of filters**, **number of classes**, and **class names** before training your model. The model you are using is probably pre-trained on some other data-set for vehicle detection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

But I already did the things you said.

Which pre-trained model should I do?

Comment: In my opinion this is not because of pre-trained model. There should be some file to set the object names that needs to be edited.

Comment: Thank you! I found yolo requires "data/coco.names" ( I haven't download this). And I edited it to my classes. then it solved! Thank you for your care.^^

Comment: But.. Why is that? I used my own "object.names" file when its training. Is there any settings on cfg file?

Comment: In the link above they input the path to object names as an argument (like `darknet.exe detector train data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg darknet53.conv.74`). Probably your model is using **coco.names** instead of **object.names**.

Comment: What link? Am I able to edit it to what I need? And which directory it is?

Comment: [this link](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects) explains the details.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, Hadi.
^^ Have a blessed week.